# Python: rerun function on except block with clean call stack

Tags: python, exception

I have code which produces potentially infinite call stack (simplified):

```
def listen(self, pipeline):
    try:
        for message in self.channel.consume(self.queue_name):
            pipeline.process(message)
            self.channel.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method_frame.delivery_tag)

    except (pika.exceptions.StreamLostError,
            pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosed,
            pika.exceptions.ChannelClosed,
            ConnectionResetError) as e:
        logging.warning(f'Connection dropped for queue {self.queue_name}. Exception: {e}. Reconnecting...')
        self._reconnect()
        self.listen(pipeline)
```

If there are any network issues, it will log an error, reconnect and move further. But it will also add one extra call to call stack. So my stack trace on error will be like this:

```
...
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 1336, in _flush_output
    self._connection._flush_output(lambda: self.is_closed, *waiters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 522, in _flush_output
    raise self._closed_result.value.error
pika.exceptions.StreamLostError: Stream connection lost: ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/msworker/queue.py", line 81, in listen
    self.channel.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method_frame.delivery_tag)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 2113, in basic_ack
    self._flush_output()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 1336, in _flush_output
    self._connection._flush_output(lambda: self.is_closed, *waiters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 522, in _flush_output
    raise self._closed_result.value.error
pika.exceptions.StreamLostError: Stream connection lost: ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/msworker/queue.py", line 81, in listen
    self.channel.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method_frame.delivery_tag)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 2113, in basic_ack
    self._flush_output()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 1336, in _flush_output
    self._connection._flush_output(lambda: self.is_closed, *waiters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 522, in _flush_output
    raise self._closed_result.value.error
pika.exceptions.StreamLostError: Stream connection lost: ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pika/adapters/utils/io_services_utils.py", line 1097, in _on_socket_writable
    self._produce()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pika/adapters/utils/io_services_utils.py", line 820, in _produce
    self._tx_buffers[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pika/adapters/utils/io_services_utils.py", line 79, in retry_sigint_wrap
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pika/adapters/utils/io_services_utils.py", line 861, in _sigint_safe_send
    return sock.send(data)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

How can I rerun `listen` function from scratch, without old calls in call stack?

**UPDATE**

To avoid this issue, it is right to operate nested function and rerun it but not itself:

```
def listen(self, pipeline):
    try:
        self._listen(self, pipeline)
    except (pika.exceptions.StreamLostError,
            pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosed,
            pika.exceptions.ChannelClosed,
            ConnectionResetError) as e:
        logging.warning(f'Connection dropped for queue {self.queue_name}. Exception: {e}. Reconnecting...')
        self._reconnect()
        self._listen(self, pipeline)


def _listen(self, pipeline):
    for message in self.channel.consume(self.queue_name):
            pipeline.process(message)
```

But still, is there a way to rerun the recursive function with a clean call stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use recursion when you can use simple iteration ?

```
def listen(self, pipeline):
    while True:
        try:
            for message in self.channel.consume(self.queue_name):
                pipeline.process(message)
                self.channel.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method_frame.delivery_tag)
            return

        except (pika.exceptions.StreamLostError,
                pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosed,
                pika.exceptions.ChannelClosed,
                ConnectionResetError) as e:
            logging.warning(f'Connection dropped for queue {self.queue_name}. Exception: {e}. Reconnecting...')
        self._reconnect()
```

> But still, is there a way to rerun the recursive function with a clean call stack?

Actually, what you currently have IS a "clean call stack" - it's the *real* call stack, with one distinct frame per call (recursive or not). Some languages do "optimize" tail-recursive calls (by squashing / reusing frames), Python's designers choosed not to to make debugging easier.